# Streambase tag - is it spam?

Tags: discussion, tags, spam

I saw a tag wiki for [streambase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/streambase) [on the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7556639). I marked the wiki as spam, because the tag has had just four questions.

I don't know how notable Streambase is, or whether there's a notability requirement for a tag on StackOverflow. I've never heard of it, but that doesn't mean much.

Comment: What reason do you have to believe that it's spam?

Comment: It certainly wasn't egregiously spammy, just that the tag wiki sounded like promo text for a tag that had 4 questions. I wasn't sure how SO deals with tags like that, so came here to ask.

Comment: If the tag wiki was a low quality tag wiki, then just edit it into a quality tag wiki that meets the site's guidelines for a quality wiki.  Done.

Comment: Personally, I think that a product with 10 questions doesn't need a tag, but I guess the SO community has discussed that issue before.

Comment: Why shouldn't it have a tag?  Remember there was some point in time when the C# tag only had 10 questions.  (Probably not for long, but still.)  A product being small, but still on topic, is not a problem at all.

Comment: It's not spam, it's just that the tag wiki was copied verbatim from somewhere else, just like every other tag wiki </broken-record>

Answer (score 5):

The tag itself doesn't look like spam.  There's no wiki to indicate that it was created for nefarious reasons, and the questions that it has, while in need of some TLC, are for the most part, fine.

It's not notable, but *all* tags started small.  Hopefully this particular tag will grow to become something interesting and have a decent following of developers using [this service](http://www.streambase.com/).

Comment: OK. I didn't know if there was a notability requirement, like on Wikipedia.

Comment: "Tender Love and Care".  The questions need to be cleaned up a bit for grammar and clarity.